# $L^2$ and $L^1$ convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure

I have been given the following questions:

Consider the following measure spaces (X, µ):

I. $X = [0, 1], µ$ is Lebesgue measure.

II. X = [0, ∞), µ is Lebesgue measure.
Show examples of functions f1, f2, . . . and $f: X \rightarrow R$ such that $f_{n}$ converges to f

a.) in $L^1$ but not in $L^2$
,
b.) in $L^2$ but not in $L^1$

now for the I part , I kind of have an idea, my solution is:
a. $nχ_{[0,\frac{1}{n^2}]}$ ,  which is n between on the interval $[0,\frac{1}{n^2}]$ and 0 everywhere.

b. I said we cannot have such a scenario

now my question is for the II question, whats confusing me is the space that I have to work on, I have no starting point, any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$f_{n}=\dfrac{1}{n}\chi_{[0,n]}$, $\|f_{n}\|_{L^{2}[0,\infty)}=\dfrac{1}{n}\rightarrow 0$ but $\|f_{n}\|_{L^{1}[0,\infty)}=1$.

For counting measure, consider 
\begin{align*}
a_{1}&=(1/2,0,0,...)\\
a_{2}&=(1/2,1/3,0,...)\\
a_{3}&=(1/2,1/3,1/4,0,...)
\end{align*}
and $a=(1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5,...)$, then $\|a_{n}-a\|_{l^{2}}=\displaystyle\sum_{k\geq n+1}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}\rightarrow 0$ but $\|a_{n}-a\|_{l^{1}}=\infty$.

Comment: ooh I understand it now, thank you

Comment: What if we change our measure to counting measure and our X= {1,2,3,4,5,......, N}, how does this change?

Comment: Look at the edited answer.

Comment: thank you, greatly appreciated